# How can I remap keys to my powers in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In the single player game, I'm able to remap which number keys trigger various powers by holding down the spacebar and then, when the command window is open, dragging the power icons into whatever numbered slot I want to hotkey them to.

[image]

However, in multiplayer, I don't seem to be able to click and drag them. This is causing me a lot of frustration because I got used to a certain setup in single-player and it is causing me to slap all the wrong keys in multiplayer.

Is there a way for me to remap my powers to the number keys?

Comment: Which powers are you trying to remap?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Grenades. I've got them in slot 2 on single-player.

Comment: A way to do this for consoles would also be most welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so far you can't. they are tied down due to the fact that there are only 3 powers available. 
this is likely because it fits better with the console versions, but a lot of people dont like it because it throws off their groove from single player.

Comment: My hate for consoles grows stronger with every passing day.

Comment: yeah, key mapping should be industry standard at this point

Answer (score 3):

What you CAN do, albeit it it's a little hacky, is go into the options and map '2' to slot '3' and '3' to slot '2' or whatever. Then change it back for singleplayer. Ridiculous that it's necessary, mind.

Comment: Yeah, I and up doing that each time I change character too. (I have two on scroll up/down which are easier to use, and a "tertiary" skill to a key)